# HTML Script editor for sharepoint

Tags: html, sharepoint

The below HTML script is giving me My Name in Upper case.I want it to display like "My Name" .How can I do that ?

```
<span class="wiki_dashboard">​My<br/> </span>
<span class="wiki_dashboard">Name</span>
```

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that has to do with the CSS code.

In the CSS code in a class called wiki_dashboard there should be a line that says `text-transform: uppercase;` You will want to delete or comment out that line

```
wiki_dashboard{
   ...
   text-transform: uppercase;  //<---Delete this line
   ...
}
```